# How to unfullscreen a window without notifying it?

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

I'm trying to enhance the gTile extension by allowing it to resize a fullscreen window to a tiled area of the screen. That's a pretty common thing to do when tiling and it's pretty handy since some windows will hide some chrome when in fullscreen mode. But I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to do that.

Searching the internet led me to [this forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1080338#p1080338) which mentions EWMH and _NET_WM_FULLSCREEN. I've tried to find ways to access window manager hints but can't find anything bashing by head on Looking Glass or scanning through [the docs](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/). Is this kind of thing possible through a shell extension?

Answer (score 1):

Meta.Window is likely what you are looking for:
https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/meta4~4_api/

Setting `Window.decorated = false` may be able to remove the title bar or perhaps getting the compositor object and changing it from there. However this will still keep the address and tab bars in chrome. You may need to find another method to signal chrome to hide those.

There is not really an easy way to do this, the thread you linked is in regards to VLC and modifying it's source code.